# How to set the class="required" jquery for radios under a row and not attacheing it to the first radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Hi im at coding a form and i needed a validation form for my radio and checkbox inside my form so i searched around the net and found out that jquery 1.3+ has class="required" tag that does exactly what i wanted but

i have this section of radios :

```
<label class="label" type="radio" name="sloganch"  >Does your slogan need to be incorporated in your Logo Design ?</label>
                        <div class="inline-group">
                            <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="radio-inline" class="required" ><i></i>Yes</label>
                            <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="radio-inline" ><i></i>No</label>
                            <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="radio-inline"><i></i>Maybe</label>
                            <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="radio-inline" ><i></i>I decide later</label>

                        </div>
```

And if  i put the `class="required"` on the first radio when it calls this function it distort my radios by attaching  " This field is required" to my first radio 
and distort the complete line of radios .

Is it possible somehow to fix this to set for eg the " This field is required"  under the complete row ? thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any css connected to the "required"  class?

Comment: What happen if you apply class to the parent `div`?

Comment: gmail user : nothing it doesn't recognize this command anymore if there

Comment: nixkuroi : no it is not

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
 $("input:radio:not(:first)").addClass("test");
```

**EDIT**

This should work i have also included a js fiddle for your reference

the above code will add class test to all the radio buttons except the first

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/ka9vf6qx/)

Comment: Please add a description to your code-only answer to help others understand what your code is doing.